# how to create a txn scrapper for solana for a specific program?

Tags: web3.js

How can we read program logs and instruction data for a specific program transactions for instance I want to keep track of all the transaction which happened for a particular NFT collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to fetch all past transactions involving the mint, and then subscribe to transactions from a program or account that can change.

To fetch the past transactions, the process is:

- get all signature with `getSignaturesForAddress` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress
- fetch each transaction by signature using `getTransaction` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction
- read through each transaction

To subscribe to new transactions, you can use `programSubscribe` to see *all* transactions from a particular program, e.g. the Metaplex Program https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#programsubscribe

Otherwise, you can also subscribe to changes to a metadata or collection using `accountSubscribe` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#accountsubscribe